# Is it possible to remove elements from an std::unordered_set through bucket iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-set

Like the question says, can you remove an element from a `std::unordered_set` using a bucket iterator (`local_iterator`)? I can see two possible solutions:

- Since erase() does only accept global `iterator`s, is there equivalent functionality for `local_iterator`?
- Is it possible to obtain the equivalent global `iterator` for a `local_iterator`?

If it's not feasible, please elaborate on why it's not.

Comment: You can't use both `it` and `++it` in the same function call.

Comment: Updated, still results in the same error however.

Comment: You should read up on [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). It doesn't actually remove elements.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I removed the whole example since it's no longer of any use.

Comment: I don't see a technical reason why it wouldn't be possible to construct a global iterator from a local iterator and its corresponding bucket index, but I don't see way to do that with standard functions.

Comment: My solution to this problem was to convert `local_iterator` to `iterator` using `unordered_set.find(*local_iterator)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious answer is no, since there is no function in the
interface which supports this.  There is also no way to get to
an `iterator` from a `local_iterator`, for the obvious reason
that a `local_iterator` contains a lot less information.  (For
most implementations, I suspect that it would be fairly simple 
to implement `erase( local_iterator )`, had the standard
required it.  On the other hand, I can't think of a conceivable
use for it, which may be why the standard didn't require it.)

Comment: I doubt both "obvious" arguments. (1) What other then bucket number would be needed to turn a local_iterator into an iterator? (2) There are lots of use-cases to erase local_iterator when iterating over a bucket -- just like there are use-cases to erase iterators when iterating over the full container. Without erase for local_iterator, is there even any difference between std::unordered_set's const_local_iterator and local_iterator?

Comment: You cant think of a reason. But obviously the person that asked the question has.

Comment: _...I can't think of a conceivable use for it..._ -  I need to erase by bucket iterator to implement an efficient LRU cache, where I want to avoid duplicating a potentially large composite key in the linked list used for tracking LRU order.